# Theory on showing dense global existence of pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations, probabilistic-method

Consider a nonlinear PDE $N(x,D\,\cdot\, ,\cdot)$ and a 'problem' involving it stated in a naive function space $F$. This problem may involve the statement of initial/boundary conditions, or the presence of a forcing term (like $f$ in the nonhomogeneous equation $N(x,u,Du)=f$ ).

I am interested in showing that sufficiently strong solution exists on a dense subset of $F$.

For example, the existence of strong solutions for problems(forcing term this case) in dense subset of $F$ has been investigated equations like 
$$
\Delta u+|u|^{p-1}u=0.
$$

Many methods have been developed in order to prove 'almost sure' global existence results for these equations, meaning that sufficiently strong solutions exists with probability 1 on given subsets of $F$, with respect to some not too impulsive probability measure given on $F$.

However, I couldn't find a generic argument for showing this kind of density property.

1. Is there any? Where can I find it?
2. (Why) is it studied less than almost sure existence?

Comment: This question is probably too broad. What kind of equations are you referring to? To ask for a general theory that encompasses **all** kind of equations is already hopeless in the deterministic setting.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro - It is an argument, or method, not a theorem that should hold every time... so I would be satisfied if you give an approach that would just hold for a big class of pdes(that does not always have everywhere global existence).

Comment: For example, a method that works 'mostly' well on 'slightly supercritical parabolic pde with certain kind of a priori bound' would be such.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. You don't want **almost sure** global existence; you want global existence **for all data in a dense set**. Am I right? Your question is not very clear. Another problem is that you speak of "global existence", which makes me think of an evolution problem, but then you write as an example a stationary problem. What do you mean by "global existence" for the equation you mentioned?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro - I see. I will change the order of the paragraphs. Besides, 'Global existence' was written to avoid 'local existence' for evolution problems; since that's all I meant there, you may ignore that for the elliptic example.

Comment: Thank you for your correction.

Comment: /Yes, you understood correctly, and a sentence had been deleted after another man's edit and I didn't notice it(...) that's my mistake, I corrected the question(might still seem rough) Thank you again for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The context is too general to obtain sensible answers.

According to Hadamard, a problem is *well-posed* when it admits a unique solution for each choice of the data, and such solution **is a uniformly continuous function** of the data. Now, a uniformly continuous function defined on a dense subset of a complete metric space can be uniquely extended to a continuous function defined on the whole metric space.

This means that any Hadamard-well-posed problem will never exhibit the phenomenon you are looking for.